# Forecasting weekly data with ARIMA and tsibble for year with 53 weeks

Tags: r, tidyverse, forecasting, arima, tsibble

I am trying to forecast some weekly data in a tsibble format with train data from 2013 to 2016.

In 2015, I have year week W53 with NA.

[Results with W53 and NA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUYsu.png)

Then, I join W52 and W53:

## join yearweek W52 and W53

train2 <- ts_2020_filled%>%
`wk1 <- yearweek("2015 W52") wk2 <- yearweek("2015 W53") seq(from = wk1, to = wk2, by = 2) wk1 + 0:9`

## Fit arima model after joining W52 and W53

`fit_ARIMA <- train2 %>% model(ARIMA(Perc_positive))`

When I try to fit arima model I got this message:

`Warning message: 1 error encountered for ARIMA(Perc_positive) [1] .data contains implicit gaps in time. You should check your data and convert implicit gaps into explicit missing values using` tsibble::fill_gaps() `if required.`

I expect to be able to run arima model with yearweek 52 (without week 53) for year 2015.

Please, could someone give a suggestion in this case?